# Speed up for SequencePredictorFunction?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, expression-test, sequence, markov-process

From Google Dive:
 `SequencePredictorFunction` is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eCujvNgFLIBTxmQk3J02SPxNBNQ9Ka2r), along with my [test data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n1uoMI44dbxgdcPA5AgQuzOuFREHXM6M).

From pastbin:
 [prediction function](https://pastebin.com/Af4Ydz87) and data is [here](https://pastebin.com/aMEaxBtn).

Using the `.mx`

```
sq = Import["seq_go.mx"];
res = Import["listall.MX"];
```

Now get ready to test the predictions: (I think this is what needs performance tunning??)

```
myCompare[list_] := Module[
   {nlist, predict, result},
   nlist = Length[list];
   predict = 
    Prepend[sq /@ Table[Take[list, n], {n, 1, nlist - 1}], "NA"];
   result = MapThread[Equal, {predict, list}];
   result[[1]] = Count[result, True]/nlist // N;
   result
   ];
myCompare[res[[1]]]
```

> > {0.4375, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True,  False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True,  True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, True,  True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False,  False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, True,  False, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True,  True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True,  True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False}

This is only for one run. If I then do

```
(myCompare /@ res;) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.299, Null}

Suppose if the `Length[res]` is 200,000. It would take a long time. I am wondering if there is any way to improve efficiency here (and keep each True/False)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to import the `.mx` files because of version problem. If the function is not big, try pasting it here. Also, for the test data you may want to use `pastebin`.

Comment: ... or export it as package (`.m`)...

Comment: @AnjanKumar @Henrik Due to the "large" data I used to generate the `SequencePredictorFunction`, I don't think (.m) actually saves anything apart from the raw code. I feel that the main problem would be the in `myCompare`, which might need performance tunning?

Comment: @AnjanKumar I have updated the pastebin links. Please let me know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I tried the code. Right at the beginning `myCompare` makes a call `sq[{"B"}]`. This does not get evaluated for `sq` is merely an association wrapped by `SequencePredictorFunction`. I would at least expect either some `DownValues` assigned to `sq` or some `UpValues` assigned to `SequencePredictorFunction` in order to make it working. Maybe, you also want to export the definitions of `SequencePredictorFunction`?

Comment: Btw. When trying to ping other users in the comments with @, it does only work if it is right in the beginning. Thus, I haven't been pinged and I stumbled into this post again just by chance...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, I think `@` can only ping one user at a time for each comment. I followed the example from MMA's manual/help, I think `sq` here works exactly as the `SequencePredictorFunction` ??

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm off then. `SequencePredictorFunction` was introduced in MMA 11.1; I am still working with 11.0.1.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu It looks like the function `sq` is the bottleneck. For the provided `res`, looking at `a0 = Table[Take[#, n], {n, 1, Length[#] - 1}] & /@ res; CountsBy[Tally[Flatten[a0, 1]], Last]`, there are `731` different sequences which are used for evaluation, because of which `Memoization` may not be of much use here. However, as you mention, length of `res` can be 20000, in such cases `Memoization` may help.

Comment: @AnjanKumar I thought I am using 'different' histories/list to predict the outcome progressively? Anyway, how/where would I add the 'Memorization'? I will give it a go after work.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Are you saying the output of `sq` depends on the previous evaluation? It doesn't look like that. If that's not the case, you may define a function f, `f[x_] := f[x] = sq[x]` which can be applied to those which are repeatedly evaluated and `sq` on other sequences, and of course, the performance gain completely depends on the number of same elements in `res`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Sorry I misunderstood you. Yes, I tried. It helped a little bit.